# Selected Listbox item to be displayed in textbox using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a task to Append Selected multiple items being selected from a listbox to a Textbox.
I have tried Implementing the code using Jquery as:

```
$("#<%= ListBlankToken.ClientID %>").change(function () {
            var SelectedITem = $("#<%= ListBlankToken.ClientID %>").select.toString();
            $("#<%= txtManagedocumentpage.ClientID %>").append(SelectedITem);
        });
```

It doesn't append selected item into a textbox.Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`append()` not working with `Text object` it works with `DOM element, HTML string, or jQuery object`

This is what you want:

```
$("#<%= ListBlankToken.ClientID %>").change(function () {
    var SelectedITem = $("#<%= ListBlankToken.ClientID %> :selected");  
    SelectedITem.each(function(){
        $("#<%= txtManagedocumentpage.ClientID %>")
                .val($("#<%= txtManagedocumentpage.ClientID %>").val() + 
                $(this).text() + ',');
    })
});
```

### Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gVYR/)

Answer (score 0):

Please read [JQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/val/) for your references.

after that, try this code:

```
var SelectedITem = $("#<%= txtManagedocumentpage.ClientID %>").val() + $("#<%= ListBlankToken.ClientID %>").val();

$("#<%= txtManagedocumentpage.ClientID %>").val(SelectedITem);
```